# Discord bot to say specific thing on specific input

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wrote a small bot in python for discord and got working simple $print function but I want to add a simple function when you input a specific word like `$cat` it returns `cats are good` or maybe an image/gif of a cat. I tried making it with this.

```
@bot.command(NAME="hello")
    await ctx.channel.send("hi there")
```

basically, I wanted to output `hi there` when `$hello` was inputted. but when I try to run the python file it crashes instantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is pretty much wrong

Below is the revised code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hi there")
```